# Mapping macros with respect to the source file that calls it

Tags: c, macros, header-files

I am using a macro(debug_macro) for logging debug info that is defined in log.h file. I need to map this debug_macro to process specific debug macros. I have explained my expectations in the below example.

```
   log.h
   =======
   #if callee==process1
   #define debug_macro proc1_debug_macro
   #if callee==process2
   #define debug_macro proc2_debug_macro

   process1.c
   ===========
   #include log.h
   debug_macro   <<<<<====== this one should call proc1debug_macro

   process2.c
   ===========
   #include log.h
   debug_macro   <<<<==== this one should call proc2_debug_macro
```

I am newbie to C programming.Please provide me any suggessions on how to implement this ? Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Move the define to the `.c` file, then you don't need conditionals at all.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do, please explain. Because, as @Mat suggests, why do you need these macro's at all?

Comment: Depending on why you have two different versions, you may find it advantageous to use `__FILE__` instead.

Comment: Hi, Basically I am porting the debug logs from one platform  to other...I have too many .c file for one process and everything is already defined as debug_macro, hence I dont want to go into all files and define them individually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the face of it, you are missing some definitions and you need to define `callee` before you include the header:

#### log.h

```
#define process1 10
#define process2 20

#if callee==process1
#define debug_macro proc1_debug_macro
#elif callee==process2
#define debug_macro proc2_debug_macro
#else
#error callee not defined
#endif
```

#### process1.c

```
#define callee process1
#include "log.h"
debug_macro   <<<<<====== this one should call proc1debug_macro
```

#### process2.c

```
#define callee process2
#include "log.h"
debug_macro   <<<<==== this one should call proc2_debug_macro
```

I'm not convinced this is the best way to go about it, but it is closely related to what you ask for.

I'd probably use the different debugging functions (macros) directly, so that it is clear that different code is implementing the debugging in the different processes.  Or, even more likely, I'd use the same debugging code in both processes.  However, my requirements aren't necessarily the same as yours.

Note that macro names are conventionally all upper-case.  Also, in general, function-like macros are preferred to object-like macros.  That is, it would be better to have:

```
#define debug_macro(a, b c) proc1_debug_macro(a, b, c)
```

Answer (score 0):

Define general purpose macro in one file, and make simpler macro for the local file.

**log.h**

```
#define complex_macro(a, b, c) ...
```

**process1.c**

```
#include "log.h"
#define simple_local_macro(a) complex_macro(a, 2, 3)
```